# Angular MongoDB Why Am I Having a Problem Adding Details When Create a New Cart For User If Not Exist

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, mongodb, express

Hello I have been working on a E-Commerce site.  I have been stuck for a while.  I
walked away from it, now I'm back because I spent to much time on this application
to give up so I'm back. This application has a registration, login, a search for
products, when product name is chosen a popup window appears. I'm stuck because I can't add
to cart from popup or the navigation when the user chooses a product.

I started off with a fake back end.  Now I have products on the backend using MongoDB,
node.js, express and JavaScript.

From the client side the user clicks on add to cart.
From my cart service a do a post for a http request passing in the _id to my end point
I still don't get details although a cart is created

I just can't figure this out. What am I missing or doing wrong

Code Snippet below

Schema:

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose");
 const User = require('../../app/backend/users/user.model')
 const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


const CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  
  products: [
    {
   name:{
    type: String,
   },
   size:{
     type:String,
   },
   imageUrl:{
    type: String, 
   }, 
   price:{
    type: Number,
   } 
 }
],     
  active: {
  type: Boolean,
  default: true
 },
  modifiedOn: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 }
 },
 { timestamps: true }
);



 module.exports  =  mongoose.model('cartItem', CartSchema, "cartitems");
```

code snippet

```
    router.post('/getProducts/addtocart:id',   async(req, res)=> {

     var _id = req.params.id; //test this

     const name = req.body.name;
     const size = req.body.size;
     const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
     const price = req.body.price;
     const description = req.body.description;


    userId =({"_id" : ObjectId("65868ffd5a346036b447937a")});



    try{

    // -------Get users Cart ------

         let cart = await cartItem.findOne({userId:userId});



     if(cart) {      //means cart is not null

          // cart exist for user
        let itemIndex = cart.products.findIndex(p => p.name == name);

     
        //----------check if product exist
           if (itemIndex > -1) {
       //product exists in the cart, update the quantity *** have to add this***
       // cart.product[itemIndex].price = productDetails.price add ths later

              let productItem = cart.products[itemIndex];
                 cart.products[itemIndex] = productItem;

            } else{
          //product does not exist
              cart.products.push({ name,  size, imageUrl, price});

                }
 
 
         cart = await cart.save(); 
         console.log("What is cart" + "" + "" + cart );
         return res.status(201).send(cart);


     } else {   

      //no cart for user create new cart

      const newCart  =  await cartItem.create({
           userId,  _id,  
           products: [
             {
                 name, size,  imageUrl, price}] 
    
        });

       cart.products.push({ name,  size, imageUrl, price});

       /*mongoose.connect(mongoURI, function(err, db){
        assert.ok("1" == 1 );
        db.collection('cartitems').updateOne({_id:_id}, {$set: {name:name, size:size, 
       imageUrl:imageUrl, price:price}}),
       //{ $push:({name:name, size:size, imageUrl:imageUrl, price:price})}
         newCart.products.push({productId, name,  size, imageUrl, price});
 
     //db.close();

     });*/


      /* I get the req.body for _id
        console.log('Request body output '
       + JSON.stringify(req.body));
       console.log("Whats in newCart", newCart);*/

      return res.status(201).send(newCart)
 }           

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
   res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
  }

});
```

Here is my data:

```
   {
    _id: ObjectId("65f991e01f28a7f454777cd8"),
    name: 'Grey Jumper',
    size: '',
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
    1500s,when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
    specimen book.",
    imageUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/greyofftheshoulder.png',
    price: 99
 },
```

Notice the size is empty I wrote code for user to choose radio button for size
you will see it in the payload

Here is my payload:

```
 {
"_id": "65f991e01f28a7f454777cd8",
"name": "Grey Jumper",
"size": "M",
"description": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
 industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
 specimen book.",
"imageUrl": "http://localhost:4200/assets/greyofftheshoulder.png",
"price": 99
}
```

I don't know were to go from here this is the last part.  I have read, researched I can't figure this out I'm stuck no matter what I try.  I got one detail  work once then it broke and cannot reproduce it. Can someone please point out the my issue.
Thanking You In Advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.  You have to find the product by id first.
ex:  var cartItem = await Products.findById({_id}) before it can be added to newCart.  This is the reason my properties were empty. Make sure you can get the id doing a console log.

Hope this helps someone

PDH